# How to set the contents of a vertical scrollview depending on what button is chosen from a horizontal scroll above?

Tags: java, android, scrollview, adapter

I was just wondering if any of you guys could give me a heads up as to what this involves?

I have used ScrollViews, I know they need a LinearLayout to scroll through and that isn't the problem.

It is that there is a dynamic horizontal ScrollView containing several buttons with buttons can be added/removed.

I also have a vertical scrollview.

The **GOAL** is to set the contents of the vertical ScrollView depending on which button is pressed in the above horizontal ScrolLView.

Any direction/insight would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ur Horizontal scroll view U have to set tag for individual views. Then in on click event of a view u can populate the vertical scroll by required data. I thinks for ur vertical scroll u can use the listview. It will be easy to handle. Also if ur horizontal  things are in more numbers then its better to use the ListView for that even..

Comment: And ListView is more efficient as it loads only what is needed, whereas ScrollView loads everything? Thanks, that sounds promising